# kubernetes: kops and IAMFullAccess policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

According to documentation of both [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md) and [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kubernetes-clusters-aws-kops/), the dedicated `kops` user needs `IAMFullAccess` permission to operate properly.

Why is this permission needed?

Is there a way to avoid (i.e. restrict) this, given that it is a bit too intrusive to create a user with such a permission?

**edit**: one could assume that the specific permission is needed to attach the respective roles to the [master(s)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/pkg/model/iam/tests/iam_builder_master_strict.json) and [node(s)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/pkg/model/iam/tests/iam_builder_node_strict.json) instances;

therefore perhaps the question / challenge becomes how to:

- not use `IAMFullAccess`
- sync with the node creation / bootstrapping process and attach the above roles; (perhaps create a cluster on pre-configured instances? - no idea if kops provides for that)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand kops design, it's meant to be end to end tool for provisioning you with k8s clusters. If you want to provision your nodes separately and deploy k8s on them I would suggest to use other tool, such as kubespray or kubeadm:

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: In that case, and since I have encountered `kubeadm` before, do we have a comparison of `kubeadm` and `kops` in terms of production-readiness & stability?

Comment: I would be more comfortable with kubespray in terms of production-readiness. Kubeadm seems to have more uses in temporary CI/getting started scenarios. But everything depends on your definitions of production-readiness.